# My female and male cats get along and are healthy, but when male goes up to play with female, she hisses and growls

Tags: cats, aggression, multi-pet-families

My female and male cats are litter mates, and they used to be a bonded pair- cannot say they still are as of now. After I had gotten both of them fixed, the female gets provoked at little things such as the male going up to her to play. She hisses and growls at the male if he tries play fighting with her, and sometimes even swipes at him with her claws out. The female cat is extremely territorial as well. They are both around a year old, and vet says they are healthy. I have tried reintroducing them to each other, but the behavior persists. What should I do?

Comment: Hi! I have a few follow up questions: how long ago did the hissing start (how long has this been happening)? How does he react when she hisses? Does he leave her alone or does he keep trying to play? When you say territorial, what else are you seeing? Is it about food? Toys? Beds/space? Your attention? And when you've tried reintroducing them, what has that looked like? How many days have you kept them apart?

Comment: The hissing started right after I had gotten the female spayed, which was around the middle of June. Depending on the situation, if the female only hisses, the male keeps trying to play. But if she starts swiping he will run away and hide, as if he's scared. The female is territorial with toys and spaces. As for reintroducing the two, I've tried somewhere between 2 weeks to a whole month.

Answer (score 1):

Let them work it out. "I'm not in the mood to wrestle" is a legitimate response. They'll figure out their own ways of interacting.

(I presume they're both neutered, or there may be subtexts...)